# Dúvidas de hospedagem de websites

Tags: aplicação-web

Bom galera sou novo basicamente em tudo desta área, passei quase 2 meses aprendendo e programando meu site por completo, tentando resolver problemas, organizar e optimizar ele ao máximo porem como sou novo ainda tenho dúvidas a certos assuntos, estou bem perto de pagar um plano de webhosting (hostinger.com.br) porem antes de fazer o pedido fui dar aquela boa e velha pesquisada para não fazer burrada, andei lendo sobre "Largura de Banda mensal" e me veio algumas dúvidas, li que dependendo de alguns fatores o uso dessa "banda" pode ser maior ou menor, alguns exemplos que li são do tamanho do arquivo html/css/jv que poderia afetar... procede isso?

outra coisinha que queria saber:

sites que hospedam vídeos e imagens no próprio servidor usam bastante "banda" então se eu substituir todas imagens/videos e alocar elas em sites externos (como imgur.com) isso seria uma boa solução?

só finalizando:

Meu site vai conter diversos vídeos porem nenhum sera hospedado ao servidor, todos serão de sites externos alem dos arquivos como html/css/jv serem bem pequenos e simples(se afetar) eu devo me preocupar com a "Largura de banda mensal" mesmo com uma quantidade de acessos (ate que razoável)?

Perguntinha bônus:

Um de alguns contatos que tive com suporte (do provedor de hospedagem que consultei) eu perguntei sobre Tráfego mensal que nos planos estão como "ilimitados" a resposta foi o seguinte:

"Segue o número de visitantes únicos por plano de hospedagem:
Gratuito: 200
Premium: 5000
Business: 10000"

(números mensais)

Premium: R$: 5,99
Business: R$: 13,99

Esses valores para esses preços estão de acordo ou eu devo procurar outros planos em outras empresas?

Agradeço atenção e me desculpem se eu cometi algum erro, aguardo respostas/dicas sobre tal assunto. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primeiramente vamos discutir o que é banda?

Para explicar de uma maneira clara, vou usar de exemplo os planos Pré-Pago de celular. Digamos que no inicio do mês lhe foram creditados *R$20,00*, durante este mês você usou o *WhatsApp, Facebook e o Instagram*, desses *R$20,00* lhe foram debitados *R$10,00* devido a utilização destes aplicativos, sobrando pra ti ainda *R$10,00* pro resto do mês. A largura da *banda* são os *R$20,00* e o tráfego de dados no servidor (arquivos HTML, CSS, JavaScript, imagens, vídeos, músicas) são os aplicativos.

## Momento Q&A

> Li que dependendo de alguns fatores o uso dessa "banda" pode ser maior ou menor, alguns exemplos que li são do tamanho do arquivo html/css/js que poderia afetar... procede isso?

**Resposta:** Na verdade arquivos de texto em geral são bem leves girando em torno de `3KB` até uns `350KB` (o que para texto é muito) a biblioteca [*jQuery*](http://jquery.com/) (utilizada amplamente em diversos sites hoje) por exemplo, gira em torno de `270KB`. Respondendo sua pergunta, SIM e NÃO, haverá um mínimo decremento de **banda** por causa do tráfego de arquivos no servidor, porém nada que seja um problema.

> Sites que hospedam vídeos e imagens no próprio servidor usam bastante "banda" então se eu substituir todas imagens/videos e alocar elas em sites externos (como imgur.com) isso seria uma boa solução?

**Resposta:** Vídeos e imagens consomem consideravelmente *banda*, é uma **ótima** prática você hospedar/alocar externamente suas mídias.

> Meu site vai conter diversos vídeos porem nenhum sera hospedado ao servidor, todos serão de sites externos alem dos arquivos como html/css/js serem bem pequenos e simples(se afetar) eu devo me preocupar com a "Largura de banda mensal" mesmo com uma quantidade de acessos (ate que razoável)?

**Resposta:** Depende, cada caso é um caso, se seguir este padrão descrito não terá problemas, a menos que o tráfego de usuários seja alta, não vejo problema algum neste *approach*.

No mundo real funciona assim, digamos que a sua **banda** mensal seja de *10GB*, supondo que o tamanho total dos arquivos no servidor seja de *300KB* mais *400KB* de arquivos externos sendo importados, com uma média diária de 20 visitantes, cabe a você multiplar esses *1200KB por 20* gerando *24000KB* (equivalente a 24MB) diário. Se mantermos este padrão até o final do mês, teremos *720MB* de *banda* usada, tendo em mente que *1GB* equivale a *1000MB* então *10GB* equivale a *10000MB*, restando-lhe ainda *9280MB* pro resto do mês.

> Esses valores para esses preços estão de acordo ou eu devo procurar outros planos em outras empresas?

**Resposta**: Acredito que está na faixa sim, olha eu nunca utilizei o *hostinger*, meus clientes usam a *hostgator*, tanto eles quanto eu nunca tivemos problema com eles :D